# Inserting an object from a derived class into another instance of said object (using the vector.insert function) C++

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I am currently working through code which has a Road class. This has a vector of lanes and includes a lane class. The lane class has a vector of vehicles and each vehicle has its derived classes (Car, Motorcycle, Lorry).
I would like a vehicle to be able to assess whether it can move into another lane, i.e. be inserted into another lane's vector of vehicles, safely (a car requires some safe distance, so I have already implemented how a vehicle knows if it is clear to switch lanes).

```
void Road::Simulate(double time)
{

for (unsigned int iLane = 0; iLane < getNLanes()-1; iLane++)
{
    for (unsigned int iV = 0; iV < getCurrentLane(iLane)->getNVehiclesinLane(); iV++)
    {
        std::cout<< " AllowedOvertake TEST "<<   getCurrentLane(iLane+1)->allowedOvertake(getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(iV)->getPosition(), getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(iV)->getMinDistance())<<std::endl;
        getCurrentLane(iLane+1)->setCanOvertake(allowedOvertake(getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(iV)->getPosition(), getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(iV)->getMinDistance()));

        if (getCurrentLane(iLane+1)->getCanOvertake() == true)
        {
            getCurrentLane(iLane+1)->insertVehicle(getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(iV), 0);
            delete getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(iV);
        }

    }
}
for (unsigned int iLane = 0; iLane < getNLanes(); iLane++)
{
    getCurrentLane(iLane)->Simulate(time);
```

}
}

I loop over all the present lanes, except the last one as any vehicle in this lane cannot overtake. After looping over the vehicles contained in each lane, I have a function which returns a Boolean which confirms whether an overtake scenario can be executed. This is done in `allowedOvertake()`. If this returns true, I implement an insert function.

My issue/question: How can I make this ideology work, and whether it is sensible to have these `setCanOvertake()` and `getCanOvertake()` functions.

One possible solution could be to just pushback a new vehicle into the intended lane, but with the appropriate positions, velocities etc. However, I am not sure how to ensure that the vehicle being entered has the same type (Car, Lorry...) too.

Currently, I do not get any build errors if I exclude the `insertVehicle()` function, and I have vehicle motion being drawn using QPainter. However, with the `insertVehicle()`  function, I do not get any build errors but I do get a crash once I run the project.

Any help would be appreciated, and apologies for any coding errors (I'm a keen, but very inexperienced C++ user).

For reference, I have the above functions' definitions as follows

```
bool Lane::allowedOvertake(double pos, double mindist)
{
    for (unsigned int iV = 0; iV < getNVehiclesinLane() - 1; iV++)
    {
        if ((fVehicles[iV]->getPosition() > pos - mindist)// If inside rear safety distance.
            || fVehicles[iV]->getPosition() < pos + mindist)// If inside front safety distance.
       {}//continue
    else {return false;}
    }
return true;
}

//IN Lane.h
bool getCanOvertake() const{return FREE_LANE_OVERTAKE;}
//IN Lane.h
void setCanOvertake(bool overtake = true){FREE_LANE_OVERTAKE = overtake;}
```

Comment: I think the problem is in `delete getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(iV);` line. You don't need to delete the object itself but simply move pointer that points to that object from one container to another - insert pointer to new container and **remove** it from another.

Comment: Hi @vahancho, even without this line, just having an insert function, which should just duplicate the vehicle, still causes a crash. I am not sure how, instead, to use the remove function, and why it should be used instead of delete

Comment: as @vahancho mentioned it looks like the delete is incorrect. From what I can tell you are moving the vehicle to another lane but then deleting it. You need to remove it from its former lanes vehicle vector instead. Deleting an object will not remove it from any vectors that contain it, but rather it will free the memory used by the object and any subsequent attempts to use it will be invalid and cause a crash. You can remove objects from vectors using the std::vector::erase() function.

Comment: I am still unsure about this explanation. I only delete the vehicle that is in the former lane. The `insertVehicle` function I have used creates a new vehicle with identical properties to the one which should move, so, once I use this, surely I can delete the object corresponding to the former lane (delete in the ith lane, not the (i+1)th lane). I may not have understood your explanation into the difference between delete and erase, apologies if this is the case.  could it be that my `insertVehicle() function is incorrect, as I only insert a vehicle which is switching lanes at the beginning.

Comment: @KarandeepGiddha, then please show how `insertVehicle()` function is implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I was under the impression I had referenced my insertVehicle() function definition.

```
void Lane::insertVehicle(Vehicle*v, int ielement) {

    Vehicle* vins = new Vehicle(v->getPosition(), v->getVelocity(), v->getAcceleration());

    for (unsigned int iDist = 0; iDist < fVehicles.size()+1; iDist++){fVehicles.insert(fVehicles.begin() + (ielement+1), vins);}
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a copy of your vehicle? You might simply insert pointer to it into the `fVehicles` vector and remove the same pointer from where it was stored before (other lane's `fVehicles` vector). Besides, your insertion `for` loop looks peculiar.

Comment: Yes, I can see I clearly do not need to make a copy of my vehicle. I have changed the `insertVehicle()` to now take in the vehicle's pointer directly. I also noticed an error, I should never have been looping over all vehicles inside `insertVehicle()`. This function should simply just insert a vehicle.